# Как добавить код на успешную отправку формы в Elementor?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, формы, elementor

Есть простая форма, там все понятно - нашел обработчик и добавил то что надо. В итоге получилось что то типа этого:

```js
jQuery.ajax({  
               url: https://some_url',      
               dataType: 'json',         
               type: 'POST',          
               data: ct_data,
               success: function (resault) {
                 console.log("успешная отправка");
                 dataLayer.push({
                 event: "Form_calculate"
             });
             },
               error: function (error) {
                 console.log("что то пошло не так")
             }
             });
```

Можно ли как то сделать то же самое для форм сделанных на элементоре? Я поискал в папке плагина и в настройках, но ничего не нашел

Comment: Нет. Вам по идее нужно прослушивать событие `submit_success` и на него добавлять Ваш `dataLayer.push()`.